# Spring session with JDBC integration

Tags: spring, session, jdbc, spring-session

I am new in Spring Session and want to use embedded database to store session information. I follow all the steps in 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc.html using spring-session-jdbc of version 1.2.0.but using Spring-web of 3.2.4 only
The following error is shown repeatly:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "spring_session" does not exist 'Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:824)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    ... 21 more'
```

This issue already haunted me for days. Please help.

Here is the xml configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessi‌​onConfiguration"/> 
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource02" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database> 
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource02"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: can you add your Config Class ??

Comment: This should never be a comment but an edit to your question (I did it for you)

Comment: Thanks, yes I should not put conf in comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you use multiple data sources, since the provided stacktrace includes PostgreSQL JDBC driver classes while you are configuring a secondary, embedded data source to storing sessions.

Spring Session configuration picks up your primary data source (PostgreSQL) and expects to find session tables there.

I'd suggest you to use your primary data source to store session data, but if you insist on having secondary/embedded data source for that purpose you need to override `JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` bean provided by `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration#sessionRepository` with your own instance which is created using your secondary data source and its appropriate tra saction manager. Note that bean must be named `sessionRepository` in order to override one from `JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration`.